# How to extract content of web pages easily which are embeded in html pages inside <body>?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to extract content of web pages easily which are embeded in html pages inside  only (like img, pdf, flv, doc, rtf, wmc etc) not css and css backgrounds images,javascript.

I'm migrating content old site to new site. re-uploading all images, linked pdf, flv etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you've used XHTML you can use a normal XML-Parser.

Answer (score 1):

The BeautifulSoup class op python is a very good parser that is extremely handy in doing operations like this.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need an HTML Parser. In Perl, there is [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Parser) module.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use Firebug addon of firefox for readonly purpose.
2. you can build your custom app using following:
   http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack